# Create a responsive CSS button with arrow

Tags: html, css, button, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a responsive button from a photoshop mockup in HTML and CSS.  Here is the button mockup:

[image]

I'm struggling with how to get the arrow in the white space and to stay there through different screen sizes.

I created the color separation through a gradient, like this:

**HTML**

```
<button> All Team Members </button>
```

**CSS**

```
button {
   /* Permalink http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#990033+0,990033+50,990033+86,ffffff+86,ffffff+100 */
   width: 70%;
   font-size: .6em;
   font-size: 3.4vw;
   padding: 2%;
   color: #ffffff;
   outline-color: #990033;
   background: rgb(153,0,51); /* Old browsers */
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(153,0,51,1) 0%, rgba(153,0,51,1) 50%, rgba(153,0,51,1) 86%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 86%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(153,0,51,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(153,0,51,1)), color-stop(86%,rgba(153,0,51,1)), color-stop(86%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(153,0,51,1) 0%,rgba(153,0,51,1) 50%,rgba(153,0,51,1) 86%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 86%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
   background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(153,0,51,1) 0%,rgba(153,0,51,1) 50%,rgba(153,0,51,1) 86%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 86%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(153,0,51,1) 0%,rgba(153,0,51,1) 50%,rgba(153,0,51,1) 86%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 86%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
   background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(153,0,51,1) 0%,rgba(153,0,51,1) 50%,rgba(153,0,51,1) 86%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 86%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* W3C */
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#990033', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

And it currently looks like this:

[image]

What is the best way to move forward?  I wondered if I should just use screenshots of the button from the mockup, or if I should make it in CSS. How can I make the button look like this and be responsive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pseudo elements `:before` and `:after`, to make the background and the arrow. Use Font Awesome etc if you need a different shape of arrow.

```css
button {
    font-size: 3vw;
    padding: 2vw;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #903;
    border: 0;
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 8vw;
}
button:before {
    content: '';
    width: 6vw;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #903;
}
button:after {
    content: '❯';
    position: absolute;
    right: 2vw;
    color: #903;
}
```

```html
<button>All Team Members</button>
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a99eshxg/)**

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.btn {padding:10px 40px 10px 20px;
    width:70%;
    border-radius:3px;
    border:2px solid inherit;
border-color: #eeeeee;
    background-color:rgb(153,0,51);
    background-position:center right;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    text-align:center;
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#990033', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
    font-size: .6em

    }
     .white_txt {color:#ffffff!important;}
     .purple_btn {border:2px solid #eeeeee;border-radius:3px;}
```

```
<div class="purple_btn btn"> 
    <div class="white_txt">All Team Members</div>
</div>
```